# Transition with white-space property CSS

Tags: css, transition

I have an issue with the white-space property, in fact, my transition bug when I remove my pointer.
You can see it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Alcest/pen/xdERob) or the snippet below.

```css
.changement {  
  margin-top:2px;
  color:white;
  font-size:1em;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  overflow: hidden;
  width:16em;
}

.changement .entete {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1.85em;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease .1s, max-height .7s ease 0s, white-space .1s ease 1s;
  padding-left:.625em;
  padding-right:.625em;
  max-height:1.85em;
}

.entete:hover {
  white-space: normal;
  max-height:8em;
}

 .technique .texte {
   background-color: #5698C4;
 }
 
 .technique .entete {
   background-color: #38627F;
 }
```

```html
<div class="changement technique" id="C14789120">
    <div class="entete"> TITRE BEAUCOUP VRAIMENT BEAUCOUP TROP LONG MAIS ALORS VRAIMENT TROP LONG !!! </div>
</div>
```

Just remove white-space and you'll see that the transition works.
Have you some tips to fix it ? 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: The transition seems to work for me without adjusting anything, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: couldn't get questions:)

Comment: the problem is that you cannot use transition on NON NUMERIC values , in your case, `white-space:nowrap` to `white-space:normal` so that's why when you mouseOut , the transition is not working. you can do this using jQuery

Comment: @er-han The transition doesn't work when you "mouse out".

Comment: as i said in my comment. you can't do it with CSS . see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231516/transition-of-height-with-white-space-nowrap-involved-possible-with-fewer-ja

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text-align to left for the .changement .entete seems to create a smooth animation on hover.

Comment: Yeah the animation works well when hover, but when you remove the mouse, the animation to close the div isn't smooth at all